# kotlin, android, json serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

i'm using google gson converter to serialize an json response from an api call into an kotlin object,

one of the json field is a json object

so this didn'T work:

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("properties")
val properties: List<ThingProperty>,
```

i got the following error:
*Api call failed: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1*

but this work fine:

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("properties")
val properties: JsonObject,
```

but i then received a JsonObject and not a list of "second level" kotlin object

So the question is, using serialization or something like that,

how can i just received the original json and convert it properly, for this field, into a list of object based on the jsonObject

note, i received my data using retrofit2

Edit:

there is a json example for this item:

```
"properties":{
        "ActiveEvent":{
            "name":"ActiveEvent",
            "value":false,
            "visible":true,
            "title":"Active Event",
            "type":"boolean",
            "@type":"BooleanProperty",
            "readOnly":true,
            "links":[{
                "rel":"property",
                "href":"/things/hydroqc-Maison/properties/ActiveEvent"
                }]
            },
        "PreHeatEvent":{
            "name":"PreHeatEvent",
            "value":false,
            "visible":true,
            "title":"Pre-Heat Event",
            "type":"boolean",
            "@type":"BooleanProperty",
            "readOnly":true,
            "links":[{
                "rel":"property",
                "href":"/things/hydroqc-Maison/properties/PreHeatEvent"
                }]
            },
        "PostHeatEvent":{
            "name":"PostHeatEvent",
            "value":false,
            "visible":true,
            "title":"Post-Heat Event",
            "type":"boolean",
            "@type":"BooleanProperty",
            "readOnly":true,
            "links":[{
                "rel":"property",
                "href":"/things/hydroqc-Maison/properties/PostHeatEvent"
                }]
            },
        "NextEvent":{
            "name":"NextEvent",
            "value":null,
            "visible":true,
            "title":"Next Event",
            "type":"string",
            "readOnly":true,
            "links":[{
                "rel":"property",
                "href":"/things/hydroqc-Maison/properties/NextEvent"
                }]
            },
```

Comment: I think you need to create ThingProperty model and annoted it as well as you did for the list so that it can be mapped to that model. Have you tried that?

Comment: Share with us the `JSON` structure that you receive from the API so that we can help you in a more accurate way.

Comment: @Pako1, yes i did, but it didn't reach that point because the first object expect a json array and not a json object

Comment: i just edited to add the json structure for this item

Comment: `properties` is not a List, is a Map, that's why JsonObject works. Change List to Map<String, ThingProperty> may works (I haven't tried parsing the whole Map object before). Or you have to manually read the `JsonObject`

Comment: @TamHuynh Thank you, that was the issue, i'm not, yet, really good with json.

Comment: What if i don't want to serialized the map, but only the object in the map?

Comment: @arist0v what do you mean by "_the_ object in the map"? The map contains _multiple_ entries ("ActiveEvent", "PreHeatEvent", ...). You could create a separate class which has properties for each of these entries if there is a fixed amount and their names are known in advance, e.g. `@SerializedName("ActiveEvent") val activeEvent: ThingProperty`, ...

Comment: @Marcono1234 Because this map (properties) contain in fact the name of the property, and the property object which is another data class, but the issue is now fixed